# how to replace favourites.xml

Tags: android-tv

I have a new xml file and I want to replace my favourites.xml file on my android TV box.  I cant find how to do it can you point me in the right direction please

Answer (score 0):

OK I have sorted it, for anyone looking for an answer the path is Android/org.xbmc.kodi/file/userdata  BUT the reason I had problems was that the files are hidden.  Unhide them an away you go